# phosphorous availability to mycorrhizae and parent plant, timing - paper search

Tags: ecology, mycology, literature, symbiosis

I'm researching phosphorous uptake in monocots to develop planting mixes for riparian planting.

I recently saw a paper suggesting (the author lacked proof) that **root zone mycorrhizae** may **solubilize phosphorous** from the soil solution **out of phase with the parent plant's ability to take up the phosphate**, resulting in P loss from the system. Sadly I didn't save the paper and so it is still out there on the net. If this is the true, and the loss significant, then it would be an argument against using mycorrhizal plants in stream-side planting.

Does this ring a bell with anyone? Failing that, what is known about the relative phasing of mycorrhizal phosphorous release and timing of plant uptake, especially in monocots?